# Replace bubbles/points in scatterplot by circular barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

While trying to visualise some data, I encountered the challenge to display circular barplots in a scatterplot.

Being used to ggplot2, I'm able to draw circular barplots, a scatterplot, but was not able to find a way to combine both of them.

I'd like to replace the points in the scatterplot, by the circular barplots.

Any ideas? Maybe another library?

Below a sample code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- structure(list(P = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                      A = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
                      B = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                      C = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                      D = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L)),
                 row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = "data.frame")
scatter_plot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=A, y=B)) +
  geom_point()

circular_barplot <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=C,y=D)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_polar(start=0) +
  facet_wrap(~P)
```

Output:
scatter_plot:
[image: scatter_plot]

circular barplot
[image: circular_barplot]

Comment: Why is this tagged plotly? Can you be more specific what is the final output suppose to look like?

Comment: Indeed, the plotly tag was a mistake (but maybe plotly allows to generate the desired configuration). Regarding the outcome, I adapted the question: I'd like to place the points in the scatterplot by the respective circular barplots.

Comment: package {circlize} might have some useful features already coded: https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize/ Also, you can use {cowplot} to draw `grobs` (e.g. `ggplot` barplot output) on other grobs (e.g. `ggplot` scatterplot): https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/drawing_with_on_plots.html

Comment: {circlize} is a really interesting package, but offers no possibility to nest the generated circular plots in a scatterplot. {cowplot} is a possibility to manually integrate the plots in the figure, but I'm looking for some "automatic" integration.

Comment: Do you just want to combine both plots? So the dots should be represented in the circular plot?

Comment: There is the [scatterpie](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterpie/vignettes/scatterpie.html) package which allows scattered pie charts in R. I'm not sure whether it will handle your circular barplots though.

Comment: @Quinten : exactly - the dots should be represented as circular plots.

Comment: @AllanCameron This goes in the right direction, but not (yet) implemented circular barplots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use `ggforce::geom_arc_bar` which allows to add pies in cartesian coordinates. Note that by code below is a quick and dirty approach to achieve your desired result for your example data.

Basically I first do some data wrangling to get the `start` and `end` for the wedges as well as the radius. Afterwards I split the data and add the circular bars via multiple `ggforce::geom_arc_bar`s. I added two parameters `r.max` to set maximum radius and offset to set the amount of "padding" between the "bars".

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)

circular_barplot <- function(.data, r.max = .2, offset = .1) {
  .data <- .data |> 
    mutate(start = (C - 1) * 2 * pi / max(C) + offset,
           end = C * 2 * pi / max(C) - offset,
           r = D / max(D) * r.max)
  .data_split <- split(.data, .data$P)
  
  lapply(.data_split, function(.data) {
    x0 <- unique(.data$A)
    y0 <- unique(.data$B)
    geom_arc_bar(aes(
      x0 = x0, y0 = y0, r0 = 0, r = r, start = start, end = end, fill = factor(C)),
      data = .data
    )  
  })
}

ggplot() +
  circular_barplot(df1) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]